# usermod: user 'sail' does not exist. Laravel sail

Tags: docker, backend, laravel-sail

I try to start my docker image using laravel sail but it fails to finish in project.test container

```
usermod: user 'sail' does not exist.

Error: Invalid user name sail in section 'program:php' (file: '/etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf')

For help, use /usr/bin/supervisord -h
```

Comment: Any updates on this? Did you manage to solve that?

Comment: Did you try a `RUN useradd sail` in your Dockerfile?

Comment: Please, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73642885/edit) and share your Dockerfile.